# Tor Browser Logging

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Trying to troubleshoot browser crashes and would like to locate log files and also enable verbose logging. What directory would I find this in and how to increase log verbosity of the Tor Browser?

Thank you

Comment: Tor Browser does not save any logs by default. What operating system are you using?

Comment: The operating system is Debian